# How do you render radio button on LWC with picklist values

Tags: lightning-web-components

How do you render the values from a picklist into multiple radio buttons groups?

```
import { LightningElement,wire, track } from 'lwc';
import { getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import LEASE_OBJECT from 
'@salesforce/schema/Lease_Payment_Term__c';
import Accounting_Type from 
'@salesforce/schema/Lease_Payment_Term__c.Accounting_Type__c';
import Type__c from '@salesforce/schema/Lease_Payment_Term__c.Type__c';

export default class GetPickListValueInLWC extends LightningElement {

@track selectedValue;
@track options = [];

@wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: LEASE_OBJECT })
objectInfo;

@wire(getPicklistValues, {
    recordTypeId: '$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId', fieldApiName : 
Accounting_Type
}) ATPicklistValues ({error, data}) {
    if(data) {
        let optionsValues = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < data.values.length; i++) {
            optionsValues.push({
                label: data.values[i].label,
                value: data.values[i].value
            })
        }
        this.options = optionsValues;
        window.console.log('optionsValues ===> '+JSON.stringify(optionsValues));
    }
    else if(error) {
        window.console.log('error ===> '+JSON.stringify(error));
    }
   }


@wire(getPicklistValues, {
    recordTypeId: '$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId',  
    fieldApiName : Type__c
}) TPicklistValues ({error, data}) {
    if(data) {
        let optionsValues = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < data.values.length; i++) {
            optionsValues.push({
                label: data.values[i].label,
                value: data.values[i].value
            })
        }
        this.options1 = optionsValues;
        window.console.log('optionsValues ===> '+JSON.stringify(optionsValues));
    }
    else if(error) {
        window.console.log('error ===> '+JSON.stringify(error));
    }
}
```

html

```
 <template>
    <lightning-record-edit-form record-id={recordId} object-api-name="Lease_Payment_Term__c"
    onsuccess={handleSuccess} onsubmit ={handleSubmit}>
    <lightning-messages>
    </lightning-messages>
    <lightning-output-field field-name="Lease__c">
    </lightning-output-field>
    <lightning-input-field field-name="Name">
    </lightning-input-field>
    <lightning-radio-group name="ATradioGroup" if:true={wiredPicklistValues.data}
                          label="Accounting Type"
                          options={options}
                          value={value}
                          type="radio"></lightning-radio-group>
    <lightning-radio-group name="TradioGroup"
                          label="Type"
                          options={options1}
                          value={value}
                          type="radio">
    </lightning-radio-group>
   <lightning-radio-group name="TradioGroup"
                          label="Type"
                          options={options1}
                          value={selectedValue}
                          onchange={handleChange1}
                          type="radio">
    </lightning-radio-group> 
    <lightning-input-field field-name="Amount__c">
    </lightning-input-field>
    <lightning-input-field field-name="Payment_Terms__c">
    </lightning-input-field>
    <lightning-input-field field-name="First_Payment_Date__c">
    </lightning-input-field>
    <lightning-input-field field-name="Generate_Payments__c">
    </lightning-input-field>
    <lightning-input-field field-name="Second_Payment_Date__c">
    </lightning-input-field>
    <lightning-input-field field-name="End_of_Month__c">
    </lightning-input-field>
    <lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small" variant="brand" type="submit" 
    name="submit" label="Submit">
    </lightning-button>
    </lightning-record-edit-form>
    </template>
```

I was able populate a single radio button group but when I added a second group the same values that are in the first radio button group is rendering in second radio group as well.  What I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its `getPicklistValues` not `getPickListValue`.

```
import { getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import YOUR_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/SomeObject__c';
```

`recordTypeId` is mandatory for the getPicklistValues.
Update the wired method as below.

```
@wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: YOUR_OBJECT})
objectInfo;

@wire(getPickListValue, {
  recordTypeId: '$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId',
  picklistFieldApi : Accounting_Type
})
wiredPicklistValues({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {
        this.options = data.values;
        console.log('data.values>> ' + JSON.stringify(data.values));
        this.error = undefined;
    } else if (error) {
        this.error = error;
        console.log('error>> ' + JSON.stringify(error));
        this.options = undefined;
    }
}
```

Use the wired result in HTML.

```
<lightning-radio-group name="ATradioGroup"
    label="Acounting Type"
    options={options}
    value={value}
    type="radio">
</lightning-radio-group>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I updated the code and I am receiving this error: 'Cannot read property 'data' of undefined'  And to confirm, it is @wire(getPickListValues,

Comment: @Phuc can you add the updated code in the question?

Comment: @Phuc JS in a case sensitive. Just noticed that, the wired property is `wiredPicklistvalues`, where V is in small case. in HTML you are using `wiredPicklistValues` which is not the same.

Comment: @Phuc If you have record types on that object, you need to provide the record type id as well.

Comment: No record types on this object. Will the values show in the browser console if they are actually being fetched?

Comment: yes, you can see that in the browser console. try the updated code. I have added another wired method to get the record type id. @Phuc

Comment: Updated code and same result.  The Radio button label does not appear.  Does that mean the there are no values in the 'wiredPicklistValues.data'?  Where in console would the values appear if they are being populated.  Rahul, I just remembered.  This LWC is inside an aura component so that I could add it to a record page.  Is that the issue?  I am overriding the 'new' button on the object.

Comment: Looks like you are getting some error in getPicklistValues method. try to log that error. To log the error you will need to use a wired function instead of wired property.  Check the updated code. @Phuc

Comment: This is a custom object.  Maybe I am referencing the object and fields incorrectly.  For the API object is it Lease_Payment_Term__c or Lease_Payment_Term?  Same for the fields.

Comment: @Phuc you always have `__c` with custom field and custom objects. Keep in mind that its case sensitive in JS.

Comment: Understood.  So does my code look correct given the custom object I am using is 'Lease_Payment_Term__c'.  thx

Comment: Yes, it does @Phuc just try debugging. your code should work now.

Comment: I will try to debug.  Error should be visible in console?  @rahul.  The object Lease_Payment_Term__c is a child of Lease__c object.  The aura component that houses the LWC is on the Lease__c object.  I am having the user create the new child record from there.  Just wondering if this is an issue

Comment: @Phuc that should not be an issue. I would recommend you to get more comfortable with Lwc, you can learn in details in these [lwc trailhead badges](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/trails/build-lightning-web-components)

Comment: I was able to get the radio buttons to populate.  But when I added a second radio button group the same picklist values are showing in both radio button groups.  Any thoughts?

Comment: You need to call the `getPicklistValues()` on each different field, also you will need a separate variable to hold those lists. @Phuc